# Linux Mint 12's MGSE interface in Ubuntu?

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell, mint, gnome-shell-extension

Linux Mint 12 is using MGSE which makes the GNOME Shell more like Gnome 2.x interface.  I would like to know if that was possible on Ubuntu and how I would go about doing that.

Comment: I reported a bug, asking for inclusion of the Mint Gnome Shell Extensions in Ubuntu repositories.
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/898811

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can [try MGSE[Mint Gnome Shell Extension]](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/11/try-new-mint-gnome-shell-extensions.html) from webupd8team gnome3 ppa:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/gnome3
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mgse-bottompanel mgse-menu mgse-windowlist
```

Or you can directly use linux mint [repository](http://packages.linuxmint.com/list.php?release=Lisa). Just add to your software sources

`deb http://packages.linuxmint.com/ lisa main`

and do

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install linuxmint-keyring mint-meta-mgse
```

Comment: Thank you very much!  msge-windowlist was the main extension I wanted!!!  Thanks again!  :)

Comment: What about the notification extension?

Comment: `Cannot add PPA: ''This PPA does not support bionic''.` Shame :(